# emmeans: Make labeled means bigger

Tags: r, ggplot2, emmeans

I'd like to make the EMMs, circled in the attached picture bigger. It looks like just increasing the y-axis label font size won't change the color-coded labels next to each wool:tension combination. Thanks for your attention.

```
model <- lm(breaks ~ wool * tension, data = warpbreaks)

emm <- emmeans(model, c("wool", "tension"))[![enter image description here][1]][1]

pwpp(emm, type = "response") +
    theme_bw() + 
  geom_point(aes(size = 3)) + 
  theme(text = element_text(size = 25)) +
  scale_size(guide = F)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be achieved via the `aes` argument of `emmeans::pwpp` which allows to set the size of labels, points and segments (see `?emmeans::pwpp`):

```r
library(emmeans)
library(ggplot2)

model <- lm(breaks ~ wool * tension, data = warpbreaks)

emm <- emmeans(model, c("wool", "tension"))

pwpp(emm, type = "response", aes = list(label = list(size = 5))) +
  theme_bw() + 
  geom_point(aes(size = 3)) + 
  theme(text = element_text(size = 25)) +
  scale_size(guide = F)
```

[image]

Comment: In designing this function, I struggled with sizing and positioning of those labels, and there is no way (that I found) to code it so it works robustly. It may be better to just suppress them altogether and display the values in some other way.

Comment: Thank you for sharing. The current solution works for me as I don't have to make the means too big. I'd like to show the means with the p-values to save some space so I appreciate `pwpp` very much.